# Help with elliptic curve experiments in SageMath

Tags: finite-groups, finite-fields, elliptic-curves, sagemath

This question may be quite basic but I'm learning about applied cryptography and abstract math isn't my strongest point.

I was just hoping for a little help to confirm a couple of things and help me figure out more about the mathematical underpinnings of elliptic curve cryptography. I believe understanding the math means understanding the technology.

I'm using `curve25519` as an experimental playground in SageMath.

```
Elliptic Curve defined by y^2 = x^3 + 486662*x^2 + x over Finite Field of size 57896044618658097711785492504343953926634992332820282019728792003956564819949
```

**Assumption I made**: The cyclic subgroup:
    `Q=2^252 + 27742317777372353535851937790883648493` is generated by using the base point `G`, generation means adding G to itself over and over. From `G+G` to `G+G 2^252+27742317777372353535851937790883648493 times`. **Is this all it means to generate a subgroup?**

**Findings:** I noticed that `G*0` and `G*Q+1` both produce the point `(0 : 1 : 0)`, **is this expected?**

I've also learned about the co-factor of an elliptic curve, for `curve25519` I understand that for cryptographic use a point must lie in the subgroup `Q` defined above and as such will have a co-factor for `8`.

Thus, points that lie in other subgroups of the curve `2Q`, `4Q`, `8Q` are not valid for cryptographic use because (**Assumption**):

1) We don't use these subgroups as they aren't prime.

2) All private keys (scalars k) must be multiples of 8 to ensure we are inside subgroup of order Q.

So generating some random points, took a while until I got one that is generated by G, and as such has a valid order of 8:

```
sage: ec.order()/ec.random_point().order()
1
sage: ec.order()/ec.random_point().order()
1
sage: ec.order()/ec.random_point().order()
1
sage: ec.order()/ec.random_point().order()
1
sage: ec.order()/ec.random_point().order()
1
sage: ec.order()/ec.random_point().order()
1
sage: ec.order()/ec.random_point().order()
1
sage: ec.order()/ec.random_point().order()
4
sage: ec.order()/ec.random_point().order()
2
sage: ec.order()/ec.random_point().order()
2
sage: ec.order()/ec.random_point().order()
2
sage: ec.order()/ec.random_point().order()
1
sage: ec.order()/ec.random_point().order()
1
sage: ec.order()/ec.random_point().order()
1
sage: ec.order()/ec.random_point().order()
8 <-- valid order
```

So my two questions are:

- **Am I correct so far in my learnings?**
- **Is there a SageMath function I can use to check if a random point belongs to the subgroup generated by G (and as such would be a usable cryptographic public key point)?**

Thank you for helping me learn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your notation is not standard. $G *G$ is not an elliptic curve operation. We have additive group operation on points $P+Q$ and scalar multiplication defined as below;

$$[a]P = \overbrace{P+\cdots+P}^{{a\hbox{ - }times}}$$ and $$P+\mathcal{O} = \mathcal{O} + P = \mathcal{O}$$ for any point $P$ on the curve and $\mathcal{O}$ is the point at the infinity or the identity element of the group.

Assuming that the order of the subgroup generated by $G$ is $q$ than
$$[0]G = \mathcal{O}$$ and $$[q]G = \mathcal{O}$$

The subgroups $2Q$, $4Q$, and $8Q$ are not interesting since they are not providing additional security due to The Pohlig-Helman algorithm. Also, while generating a random element, you may fall into the trap by selecting the small subgroup like your method. There are safer methods.

You can generate random elements by using a good random source like `/dev/urandom`

- One way by using random scalar;

  1. Choose a generator point $P$
  2. Get random integer between $ 0 < k < \text{Order of the Group}$
  3. Calculate $R = [k]P$ by a fast scalar multiplication.
- another way is rejective sampling the $x$ coordinate.

  1. Select random $x$ coordinate
  2. Calculate $y^2 = x^3 + 486662*x^2 + x$
  3. If $y$ is a quaratic redisude than choose $y$ or $-y$ else return step 1.

**answer to comments.**

> 1) is it normal that G*0 and G*q produce 0:1:0?

Note $[0]G = \mathcal{O}$ is normal and $[q]G = \mathcal{O}$ if the order divides $q$

> 2) Is there a SageMath function I can use to check if a random point belongs to the subgroup generated by G?

```
P.order()
```

> 3) the 2^252 subgroup is formed by adding G to itself q times right?

if the $G$ is generator, yes.

Comment: upvoted, thanks for the reply, to clarify: 1) is it normal that G*0 and G*q produce 0:1:0? 2) Is there a SageMath function I can use to check if a random point belongs to the subgroup generated by G? 3) the @2^252 subgroup is formed by adding G to itself q times right?

Comment: @Woodstock see the update.

Comment: thank you, so for a curve, if G.order = q then G*q == 0:1:0?

Comment: It is the standard group order where the $\mathcal{O}=(0:1:1)$ is the additive identity.

Comment: thank you, I think I'm finally starting to understand this stuff.

Comment: just re-read my question, I noticed I was wrong, I meant: G+G to G+G 2^252+27742317777372353535851937790883648493 times...... to generate the subgroup, which I think matches what you were saying... you multiply G times a scalar, if that scalar is @2^252, then that means G+G 2^252 times, right?

Comment: $[2^{252}]G$ as in the top of the answer add $G$ itself $2^{252}$-times